# KeyError: 'NOX'

Tags: python, error-handling, keyerror

Input:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
CO =[]
NO2 =[]
NOX =[]
SO2 =[]
FSP=[]
RSP=[]
O3=[]
no=0

f = open('Air Pollutants.csv') 
data = pd.read_csv(f,encoding='utf-8',header=None, sep = '\t') 


NOX=data['NOX']
NO2=data['NO2'] 

sns.kdeplot(NOX,shade=True, color="orange") # to make a figure of NOX
sns.kdeplot(NO2,shade=True, color="blue") # to make a figure of NO2
plt.show()
```

Output:

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3631, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'NOX'

Why there is a key error when I try to read the columns NOX and NO2? And how to solve this error, thanks.

csv. file as follows:

DATE,HOUR,STATION,CO,FSP,NO2,NOX,O3,RSP,SO2

1/1/2022,01,TUEN MUN,75,38,39,40,83,59,2

1/1/2022,02,TUEN MUN,72,35,29,30,90,61,2

1/1/2022,03,TUEN MUN,74,38,28,30,91,66,2

1/1/2022,04,TUEN MUN,76,39,31,32,79,61,2

Comment: Are you sure you have those columns? Are you sure they are spelled exactly the same way as in your code?

Comment: DATE HOUR STATION CO FSP NO2 NOX O3 RSP SO2

1/1/2022 1 TUEN MUN 75 38 39 40 83 59 2

1/1/2022 2 TUEN MUN 72 35 29 30 90 61 2

Comment: I'm sure either NOX and NO2 are in the coloumns

Comment: Can you try `NOX=data.loc[:, 'NOX']` and similarly for NO2.

Comment: It doesn't work either with same error

Comment: Can you show output from `print(data.columns)`

Comment: Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')

Comment: You are using `header=None` when reading csv so the dataframe has no column names. Delete `header=None` and it should work then.

Comment: deleted, same error remains... @@ lol...

Comment: And you still have no column names in the dataframe?

Comment: Is there an empty line at the start of the csv?

Comment: Yea, header= None seems to have no impact to the column names

Comment: There is no empty line, the first line is already the column names.

Comment: Can you try `header=0` or `header='infer'`? Do you have column names now?

Comment: both don't work. :(

Comment: Oh... why are you using `\t` as the separator? The csv is clearly comma-delimited. Just delete `sep='\t'`

Comment: print(data.columns) Output is:

Index(['Remarks:'], dtype='object')

Comment: If I remove the \t, it will become another error:


ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 12, saw 10

Comment: Can you give a link to the csv you're using?

Comment: https://cd.epic.epd.gov.hk/EPICDI/air/download/
Press Tuen Mun first, then there will be a list of options:
All parameters, hourly, Date: 1-1-2022 to 30-6-2022

Comment: Have you even looked at the csv? Can't you see that the first 11 rows are just some remarks so you need to use `skiprows=11` when reading the csv.

Comment: I deleted the first 11 rows, but there is the same error. I forget to mention, apologize for that.

Comment: Csv:
DATE,HOUR,STATION,CO,FSP,NO2,NOX,O3,RSP,SO2
1/1/2022,01,TUEN MUN,75,38,39,40,83,59,2
1/1/2022,02,TUEN MUN,72,35,29,30,90,61,2
I still cannot understand where went wrong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure what you're doing wrong but I took the file that I downloaded from the location you provided and simply did this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/home/pav/Downloads/air_hourly.csv', skiprows=11)
```

That's it. It gives me a properly formatted dataframe:

```
data.columns
# Out: Index(['DATE', 'HOUR', 'STATION', 'CO', 'FSP', 'NO2', 'NOX', 'O3', 'RSP'], dtype='object')
```

And

```
NOX = data.loc[:, 'NOX']
NOX.shape
# Out: (4344,)
```